# c++ how to count arrays within an array

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, declaration, braced-init-list

suppose I have this code :

```
int arr[] = {{1, 4}, {2}, {3, 2, 6}};
```

how do I count the number of arrays within an array, which in this case would be 3.
if the code dosen't work is there a way to get the answer with other methods?

i've searched on google and read articles

Comment: This code can't work, so the answer is zero.

Comment: This isn't something C++ knows how to work with, you can't just pitch arrays into arrays randomly. Maybe you'd do better with, as with all things in C++, `std::vector`, or in this case `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: trial and error should never be the last thing to try, but most of the time it can be the first https://godbolt.org/z/1dE8qxrjd It just does not compile

Comment: In C++ you declare an array of arrays like: `int arr[rows][columns];` and the value of `rows` is how many 1d arrays are contained in the 2d array.

Comment: given a string `"{{1, 4}, {2}, {3, 2, 6}};"` you can count the brackets. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

A one-dimsional array can not contain other arrays as its elements.

You could use for example `std::initializer_list<int>` as the element type instead of the type `int`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::initializer_list<int> arr[] = { {1, 4}, {2}, {3, 2, 6} };

    std::cout << "The array contains " << std::size(arr) << " lists\n";

    for (const auto &list : arr)
    {
        std::cout << '\t' << std::size(list) << ": ";
        for (const auto &item : list)
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
The array contains 3 lists
        2: 1 4
        1: 2
        3: 3 2 6
```

Otherwise you could declare a two-dimensional array like for example

```
int arr[][3] = {{1, 4}, {2}, {3, 2, 6}};
```

In this case each element of the array has the type `int[3]`.

Again you can use the standard C++ function `std::size` declared in the header `<iterator>` to get the number of elements in the array. Or you could simply write

```
const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );
```

`N` will be equal to `3`.

Another approach is to use standard container `std::vector`.

For example

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr = { {1, 4}, {2}, {3, 2, 6} };
```

You may use the same standard function `std::size( arr )` or member function size like `arr.size()`.

Comment: `A one-dimsional array can not contain other arrays as its elements.` I would argue with that! `auto arr[] = { {3,4}, {3,5}, {4,5,7}};` Two-dimensional array is a one-dimensional  array of arrays of same size.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Two-dimensional array is not a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: That statement's only true if you drop the words "one-dimensional".  A two dimensional array is an array of arrays.  The rank cannot be one and two at the same time.  You can have algorithms that operate on the outermost dimension, and therefore work on both one-dimensional arrays and two-dimensional arrays.  But that doesn't mean the latter has rank 1.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I would argue that standard LITERALLY doesn't define two-dimensional array. Any rules regarding two-dimensional, or more, are inferred by induction from one-dimensional. That's exactly why we can leave  only *the left-most size specifier* empty. Because following ones are defining the type of array's elements. with `auto` I wasn't  exactly fair, because in that case each element is an `initializer_list<int>` actually, which allows to create a ragged array but doesn't allow to use dual brackets to access an element. You have to do `arr[i].data()[j]` or use iterators

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie From the C++ Standard "3 When several “array of” specifications are adjacent, a multidimensional array type is created; "

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The quote is from the C++ 17 Standard. The same is written in C Standards.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Section "11.3.4 Arrays", p. # 3.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow found. That declaration section. THey did inconsistent spelling there, but that filled hole  of definitions in prior versions, where they referred multi-dimensional array initialization, but not the such.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't work. You're declaring singe-dimensional array of type `int` and try to  initialize each `int` element with a nested brace-enclosed initializer list.
More of, ***an array may contain elements ONLY of same type***. Arrays of different size are different type, so what you tried to imply is outright impossible.

You can use one of dynamic containers in nested way, e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. But for sake of knowledge or  absolute, inescapable need to have a statically-sized array:

```
 int arr[][3] = {{1, 4}, {2}, {3, 2, 6}};
```

Note, that in this case all elements are arrays of size 3. Rest of elements are initialized to 0. For any array following is true:

```
count_of_subarrays = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

As long as `arr` name here is actually an array and not a pointer, it would work. You divide total size of array by size of its first element. Since C++17 there is a helper which does that:

```
count_of_subarrays = std::size(arr);
```

Ragged, but statically-sized arrays may be implemented by creating a more complex structure, eg. actually storing sizes of elements in your structure. I.e. you would have an array of element values, an array of sizes\indices and re-defined `operator[]`